# Git status shows changes after git reset -- hard, 2nd checkout -- removes change

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

For roughly one month now, I have a strange problem with git.

I work with Intellij in a large project with lots of commits, we use gerrit for code reviews and coordination.

Often I have to reset local changes or use intellij to rebase my changes.

- For a while now rebases fail because git can't properly reset files
- The content of a file is properly reset but some flags or metadata are still changed.
- Git Diff does not list any changes
- Only after a second "checkout -- file" (intellij: revert changes), files are listed as 'unchanged'.

I have attached a minimal example which shows that behavior:

```
user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d
$ mkdir gittest

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d
$ cd gittest/

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/gittest/.git/

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ echo test >> pom.xml

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ git add .

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ git commit
[master (root-commit) e498342] testcommit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 pom.xml

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ echo test >> pom.xml

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   pom.xml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ git checkout -- pom.xml

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   pom.xml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ git diff

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ git checkout -- pom.xml

user@Windows10 MINGW64 /d/gittest (master)
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Same behavior with git reset --hard, only a consecutive git checkout -- file removes all changes.

Environment: Windows 10, Eset Antivirus, git version 2.16.0.windows.2, same behavior on SSD and HDD

Comment: Not an answer, but sometimes I have seen IntelliJ mess around with line endings automatically, without you knowing about it.  You should do a diff in IntelliJ after running the first `git checkout -- pom.xml` to see what the purported changes are.

Comment: Tried it, Intellij says: "Contents are identical", with "Do not ignore" for whitespaces and "Show whitespaces=on" in diff settings.
But it is still listed as a changed file...

Comment: Very strange.  And just so that your question is clear for others, you are seeing this from the command line, IntelliJ, or both?

Comment: Both, I have to reverts files in intellij 2 times to remove them from "Local changes" and that minimal example was done completely in Git bash terminal

Comment: This is probably a Windows-specific bug with the index metadata. As a horrible workaround, you can remove the index file (`rm .git/index`) and then run `git reset` to rebuild it from the `HEAD` commit. Note that this loses any modifications you made to the index yourself on purpose.

Comment: I tried deactivating windows indexing for the projectdir, but problem still persists :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, but its rather unsatisfying:
Delete git for windows and install lastest version (2.17.1.windows.2 in my case)

Disabling windows search indexing did not work, nor playing around with git settings or reseting git index.

I can only assume my git installation got somehow corrupted and had some kind of commit hook or other commit specific problem.